# gridx module undefined error while loading

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx, gridx

I'm having issues with Gridx while using IndirectSlect and below is my code

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-attach-point="metadataGrid" data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
     <div id="updateMetadataManagerGrid" data-dojo-attach-point="updateMetadataManagerGrid" data-dojo-type="gridx.Grid" 
     data-dojo-props="cacheClass: 'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync',barTop: [
              { content: '<h3>Document Update Requests</h3>', style: 'color: blue;' },
               {pluginClass: 'gridx/support/QuickFilter', style: 'text-align: right;'}
          ],modules: [
                'gridx/modules/IndirectSelect',
                'gridx/modules/RowHeader',
                'gridx/modules/Pagination',
                'gridx/modules/pagination/PaginationBar',
                'gridx/modules/SingleSort',
                'gridx/modules/Filter',
                'gridx/modules/filter/FilterBar',
                'gridx/modules/extendedSelect/Row',
                'gridx/modules/VirtualVScroller',
                'gridx/modules/extendedSelect/Row',
                'gridx/modules/Focus',
                'gridx/modules/move/Row',
                'gridx/modules/CellWidget',
                'gridx/modules/Edit',
                'gridx/modules/ColumnResizer',
            ]",selectRowTriggerOnCell: true,>

     </div> 
     </div>
```

When I run my code, in IE&Firefox console, I see an error message as shown below. Basically, two modules are not found while gridx creation.

The 1-th declared module can NOT be found, please require it before using it: gridx/modules/IndirectSelect

The 2-th declared module can NOT be found, please require it before using it: gridx/modules/RowHeader

Please help.

Regards,
Manju

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the modules in the file that you use the grid.

[image]

And then you call it in the grid declaration.

```
var grid = new Grid({modules: [indirectSelect, RowHeader]})
```

Comment: Well, I think, this is true when you want to create gridx programmatically. Here I'm trying to create gridx through templated widget approach. I have some gridx's created the way you said and they work fine.

Comment: @ManjunathaMuniyappa Have you required those modules also in your widget module or they are specified only in template?

Comment: @barbsan, I don't have them declared within my widget just only in a template.

Comment: I also tried doing something like this  but no luck                                                                                     gridx.modules.push({
   "moduleClass":'gridx/modules/select/Row',
   "multiple":"Multiple",
   "selectByIndex":true,
   "triggerOnCell":true
  },
  {
   "moduleClass":'gridx/modules/IndirectSelect',
   "all":true
  });

Comment: Ok now, I included all modules as suggested by @Stefano

I can see checkboxes expect a checkbox on the header(where users can select all items)

Comment: I don't know why because I have the checkbox on the header to select all items.